# How do you calculate the voltage output of a common emitter amplifier

Tags: amplifier, common-emitter

How would you calculate Vout given Rc, Vce and Re? I used the voltage divider and got a strange answer. I'm asking this because there was a question on my advancement exam that made me think of this scenario.

[image]

Comment: All the required formula are on your diagram. What calculations did you do and what result did you get?

Comment: I would choose R1,R2 such that Vc=7V (V+* 1/2  + 1) based on Ve/Re and Vbe=0.65 to 0.7

Comment: I would also choose R1/R1=Rb=20x Re to eliminate hFE variations and all these are derived from Rc,Re, and V+ then Vc , Ve thus Vb

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I developed while at university. It always works. It is not optimal. It gives insight.

Purpose: bias base at 1/3 of VDD. Set V(re) = V(rc), to guarantee 1/3VDD as headroom.

Thus R1= 100K, R2 = 50K. Make Re = 1/10 of R2 = 5K. Make Rc = 5K.

For this, Vb ~4v, Ve ~3.35v. Vc = 12 - 3.35 = 8.65v.

Note you have appromately symmetric swing possible, about the Q-point of 8.65v.

This method only fails if the Beta is extremely low. Very high Betas are not a problem.

Comment: This was my favourite screening question when interviewing engineering candidates. Most would flounder. For those that did sail through getting the thing biassed, I could then ask about dynamics, Miller cap and suchlike. Your values are pretty much identical to my solution.